# JMS 2.0 QueueBrowser on Wildfly does not return messages

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly, java-ee-7, hornetq

I have 2 simple EJB beans.
The first one is a timer method that is called every second. In this method I add 10 random messages to a TestQueue.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Timer {

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/queue/TestQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/1", persistent = false)
    @AccessTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.DAYS, value = 1)
    public void addToQueue() {
        for(int i = 0; i<30; i++)
            context.createProducer().send(queue, "msg " + (new Random().nextInt(100)));
        printQueueSize();
    }

    public void printQueueSize() {
        QueueBrowser qb = context.createBrowser(queue);
        Enumeration enumeration = null;
        try {
            enumeration = qb.getEnumeration();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int size = 0;
        while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            enumeration.nextElement();
            size++;
        }

        System.out.println("Queue size: " + size);
    }
}
```

Second bean is a MDB consumer. I put Thread.sleep(100) to simulate long running task and make sure that there are some messages in TestQueue.

```
@MessageDriven(
activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/queue/TestQueue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1")
}) 
public class Consumer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that console output shows:

```
15:06:29,006 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) Queue size: 0
15:06:30,006 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 10) Queue size: 0
15:06:31,009 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 1) Queue size: 0
```

etc.

but in the wildfly admin console I can see that there are more and more messages every second:

[image]

The question is, why the QueueBrowser return empty Enumeration? Is it a bug in HornetQ implementation or there is some reason for that?

Comment: I am not sure whether your way is correct, but I used the JMX way to programmatically read thw queue size and it works correctly.

Comment: could You provide some example please?

Answer (score 1):

Although this will not answer your question, I will show how I get the queue size in HornetQ, in an EJB Service:

```
    InitialContext initialContext = null;
    try {
        // Step 1. Create an initial context to perform the JNDI lookup.
        initialContext = getContext();

        // Step 2. Perfom a lookup on the queue
        Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("jmx/queue/YOUR_QUEUE_NAME");


        // Step 7. Use JMX to retrieve the message counters using the
        // JMSQueueControl
        ObjectName on = ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT
                .getJMSQueueObjectName(queue.getQueueName());
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://localhost:9990"), new HashMap<String, Object>());//this is the URL for WildFly 8.2 (should work for all 8.X)
        MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        JMSQueueControl queueControl = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(mbsc, on, JMSQueueControl.class, false);

        // Step 8. List the message counters and convert them to
        // MessageCounterInfo data structure.
        String counters = queueControl.listMessageCounter();
        MessageCounterInfo messageCounter = MessageCounterInfo.fromJSON(counters);


        queueControl.getConsumerCount();//this returns consumer count
        queueControl.getMessagesAdded();//returns messages added from the last time we checked
        queueControl.isPaused();//prints out, whether the queue is paused (you can stop a queue from being processed e.g. from JMX)
        queueControl.getMessageCount();//message count so far

    } finally {
        // Step 17. Be sure to close our JMS resources!
        if (initialContext != null) {
            initialContext.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`printQueueSize()` is returning zero because you are calling it from within `addToQueue()`.

Your messages are not on the queue yet because the transaction that was started just prior to entering `addToQueue()` will not be committed until the `addToQueue()` invocation returns (without errors).

JMS operations are transactional.

Comment: As You can see on the screenshot there were hudreds of transactions commited already, the JMS consumer is invoked every 100ms(after delay) and Wildfly console shows proper queue size. Transactions are not the issue here.

Comment: I agree that you should be able to see remaining messages from previous calls to `addToQueue`. However, you will not see the messages added in the current call.

Comment: Mind you, that `Thread.sleep(100)` means that your MDB will be consuming messages at almost 10 per second, which is the same rate at which you're adding them.

Comment: Good point, but when I increased the number of produced messages to 20, or 30 there is still 0 size.

Comment: we have the same problem now with Wildfly 10 (was the same with Wildlfy 9 and HornetQ) and a synchronous MessageReceiver, which works fine, but queued messages are not returned by the now ActiveMQ management queue, e.g.:
`Queue managementQueue = ActiveMQJMSClient.createQueue("activemq.management");`
connecting to the consumer will properly show the queued message *count*, but not return any messages for the same queue via `listMessages` ?!

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head against this issue for days and finally found out that in our case, it was that the queue was configured to be `transactional`.

This means that according to JMS 2 specs, the messages are consumed and put into a transaction at the `Consumer` side, so they are not contained in the Queue anymore, but also don't show up anywhere else, it's like a transparent buffer.

see [JMS 2 Session API docs](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/Session.html):

> A session may be specified as transacted. Each transacted session supports a single series of transactions. Each transaction *groups a set of message sends* and a *set of message receives* into an atomic unit of work. In effect, transactions organize a session's *input message stream* and output message stream into series of atomic units. When a transaction commits, its atomic unit of input is acknowledged and its associated atomic unit of output is sent. If a transaction rollback is done, the transaction's sent messages are destroyed and the session's input is automatically recovered.
>
> The content of a transaction's input and output units is simply *those messages that have been produced* and consumed within the session's current transaction.

Simply setting the attribute `transaction` to `none` in Wildfly's config (usually `standalone-full.xml`) solved the issue:

```
pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="none"
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25246084/160799 for a practical explanation covering HornetQ (it's the same with Artemis/ActiveMQ)